# return float array

Tags: java, arrays, return

How can this be done in one line? This is inside a function/method. I am trying to return an array.

```
float[] t = { 
    lat, lng
};
return  t;
```

Comment: Your additional lines haven't improved the question's quality...

Comment: @Andreas_D I think the question was clear enough with just those few lines. Poor spelling of the phrase "of course" is the only issue here, and grammar is fine.

Comment: One line: `float[] t = {lat, lng};return  t;` :P

Comment: clankill3r, you should accept an answer if either Jeffrey's or my answer solved your problem. Whichever answer helped you the most is the one you should accept.

Answer (score 10):

```
return new float[] { lat, lng };
```

Comment: now i upvote and your overall rep. is over 4000 =) of course this is the pure correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Either use Jeffrey's idea or you can create a record:

```
public static class Position{
    float lat;
    float lng;
    public Position(float lat, float lng){
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}
```

And then you can pass around a Position:

```
return new Position(lat, lng)
```

Jeffrey's is better if you want it for your own application that no one will see and you will use once. This is better if you're publishing this in any way, or if you're using it in multiple methods, called from various places (because it's easier to read).

Also, a record can be better if you're passing it around a lot, because it helps keep track of things. The again, if this is just for one method that's used in one place, it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @Jeffrey Oh noes :'( I fixed it.

Comment: You still missed a spot in your second to last paragraph :P

Comment: @Jeffrey Aha! I think I swatted all mistakes now!

Comment: Indeed you did. And of course, returning an object for data like this is almost *never* a bad idea. +1

Comment: @Jeffrey Thanks. It does have some memory disadvantages (minor... why are you using Java if you care that much?). Also, it can be waste of time if it's just for one use. If you pass around too many arrays, however, you can get confused and your program falls apart.

Comment: Another advantage of the record is that you can validate lat and lon values rather than accepting any old rubbish ;-)